# Sass::SyntaxError when using Bootstrap in Rails application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, sass

I installed twitter bootstrap by copying the files into my assets directory as per the instructions here: http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application/

After following the instructions exactly as presented and executing "rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development", I am able to use bootstrap 3 in my development rails server.

However, when I try to execute "heroku run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production", I get this error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ss","sources":[": expected "|", 
was ""less/theme.les..." (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css) (sass):444
```

I am not sure what this means. When I open "application.css" in the assets/stylesheets folder, I can't even find a line 444. I do have some scaffold files left over after running "rails g scaffold ..." commands -- could that be causing this problem? And obviously, the deployed heroku app looks like a non-bootstrap app when I view it from the heroku page and throws a "resource not found" error.

In public/assets/application-mydigest.ccs, I found the following line of code that causes the error:

```
{"version":3,"file":"bootstrap-theme.css","sources":["less/theme.less","less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less","bootstrap-theme.css","less/mixins/gradients.less","less/mixins/reset-filter.less"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAeA;;;;;;EAME,0CAAA;EC+CA,6FAAA;EACQ,qFAAA;EC5DT;AFiBC;;;;;;;;;;;;EC0CA,0DAAA;EACQ,kDAAA;EC7CT;AFqCC;;EAEE,wBAAA;EEnCH;AFwCD;EG/CI,0EAAA;EACA,qEAAA
```

However, it seems odd that this would only happen on production. Moreover, the CSS syntax looks fine.

Comment: You're trying to compile `less` files with the `sass` preprocessor. That isn't going to end well.

Comment: Do you know how I could just disable whatever's causing the problem? I don't really know why it happens only in production mode.

Comment: start with what assets you have - do you have an `application.css`, or `.css.scss`, or `.css.less`? what's in it?

Comment: I have a bunch of .scss files, along with application.css and all the .css files associated with bootstrap. The bootstrap installation seems to be a normal install, following the instructions in the article linked in the OP, which is why this is puzzling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means the assets compilation failed because of an invalid css syntax into a file you require in application.css.

In bootstrap repository there is a less directory and you can't precompile less files with rails.

If you want to use Rails and Bootstrap on a production environment I think use [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) is a better option

Comment: I ended up using this link: http://rvg.me/2014/01/adding-bootstrap-from-a-cdn-to-your-rails-application/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using rails-assets instead of the referenced method of adding Bootstrap 3? I use it on Heroku with success... and just add my own custom Bootstrap css in my normal assets folders which get loaded after the vanilla Bootstrap 3 and override it. Just add **gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap'** along with **source 'https://rails-assets.org'** to your gem file. May help diagnose if nothing else.

Comment: This gave me a "less" compilation error, but thanks for trying, I guess.

Comment: Do you have the 'less-rails' gem installed? I think it has some issues with certain versions while using Bootstrap.

Comment: Also, do you have any preprocessor gems such as less-rails, sass-rails etc that are in the development or production group of the gemfile but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

EIther of the two things you must take care to avoid assets compilation errors when you go live.

**- Add all your assets(js/css) in manifest file(application.js/application.css) 
- OR
 - use assets.precompile=%w(custom.css custom.js) directive to handle them explicitly**

because when u precompile...rails copies everyting(images/fonts) except js/css into public folder to be taken care by the server(apache),hence the setting   `# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed  config.assets.compile = false` in `production.rb` during assets precompile fallback is disabled by default in production/staging as Rails assumes it will be handled by webserver.Hence we have manifest file to define our assets which gets precompiled during assets:precompile and verified by looking for public/assets/javascripts/application.css/js after compilation which gets created requiring all files mentioned in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css and app/assets/javascripts/application.js after running assets:precompile...so hope u know where you missed.

FOR MORE DETAILS..REFER [this](http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/116-12-tips-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline)